# Google Assistant on Raspberry Pi 3 - Running sample code - error Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

Using a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian GNU/Linux 9, on a Marty Robot, having installed the Google Assistant SDK as described on the official page

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/

Trying to execute the last step:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/run-sample

I expect it to work, simply to work.

But I've got the following Error:

```
(env) pi@martina:~ $ googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project_id "martinaaiy" --device_model_id "Martina"
device_model_id: Martina
device_id: 8375BDBA056A04CCB8EBDAF685DC07B5

https://embeddedassistant.googleapis.com/v1alpha2/projects/martinaaiy/devices/8375BDBA056A04CCB8EBDAF685DC07B5 403
[6130:6148:ERROR:assistant_nupnp_client.cc(103)] Cloud discovery nupnp request failed: [60] Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
[6130:6148:ERROR:assistant_nupnp_client.cc(103)] Cloud discovery nupnp request failed: [60] Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
  {'is_muted': False}
ON_START_FINISHED
[6130:6148:ERROR:assistant_nupnp_client.cc(103)] Cloud discovery nupnp request failed: [60] Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with a few other engineers, this error is being logged due to some legacy features that are being deprecated. It should not impact you from actually running the sample and the error will be removed in an upcoming SDK release.

See https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/192 for more information.

Comment: oh god, I didn't try to say "Ok, google". I'll do as soon as I arrive home.

Thanks Nick!

Comment: It works, its just an error printed on the screen but the assistant works.